# How can i relate issue id in jira to commit id in git?

Tags: git, jira

I have came across a condition for which i am not able to find any solution.

I am doing a project in which i need to take open source project say Hibernate and from JIRA of hibernate i need to get the issue id and then relate the issue id to a commit id to find out , the commit which fixed the particular issue and if possible the files that ever changed due to the fix.

Progress:
I was able to access JIRA of hibernate and was able to get the issue id.
Also i am able to clone the hibernate repository and get commit id's.
Now how can i relate these two.

Comment: Are you submitting your changes or build some data about existing commits?

Comment: I am trying to due case study on the existing projects . I wont be making any changes to the existing commits . I just want the data

Answer (score 0):

Run this command to get the commit information :

```
git log --all --grep="issue_id"
```

Comment: HE doesnt have the jira ID in the commit message, he is asking how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add the JIRA-ISSUE-ID to the specific commit, in order to do it you will have to do a rebase to manipulate the commit message.

Another workaround can be to create your own branch starting from the desired commit and than amend the commit and add the JIRA-ISSUE-ID to it and if you are using bitbucket as your server it will automatically connect it for you.

If you are not using bitbucket you can siply add the commit id as note or a text in your task description.

[image]

Comment: This is possible for the case when i am creating my own project. I need for an existing project like hibernate, JBoss etc. the once which already was issues created.